# Occluded child view's in LinearLayout in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my layout scheme:
[image]

In `LinearLayout` on `ScrollView` I put some `LinearLayout` (2) items (right on image) with `ImageView` and `LinearLayout`(3) with `TextView's`.

But `LinearLayout` (3) occluded- and I see my `ImageView` and part of `LinearLayout` 3
[image]

How can I fix it?

**UPD** 1. Add XML
(Al TextView's has `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, ...`height="wrap_content"`)
   -- This xml of **LinearLayout 2** on images

```
 <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_box_black_24dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            ... />

                        <TextView
                            ... />

                        <TextView
                            ... />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: would help if you show us your xml layout.

Comment: Put your code for a better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Layout3's height is using "match_parent" to Layout2, while Layout2 has "wrap_content". This may be causing Layout3 to match Layout2's height which is wrapping only the imageview's height

Since it appears Layout3 has content in it, make it "wrap_content"  to see if it'll make Layout2 adjust to Layout3.

Edit: Wanted to specify height was "match_parent"

Comment: Man - you are best! Thank you. I set in LL2 and LL3 height=wrap_content, and this works!